# progress bar is smaller than its drawable causing the image to truncate

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

I am using custom progress bar with 2 images. One for background and one for the actual progress. Here is my xml for the progress bar

```
    <ProgressBar
         android:id="@+id/pbGold"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
         android:progress="20"
         android:progressDrawable="@drawable/gold_progressbar" />
```

And here is my gold_progressbar

```
<layer-list >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/empty_bar1"
        />

    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:drawable="@drawable/progress_bar1"
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"
        />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The problem is that the progress bar on the screen is smaller than it should be. I am using wrap content so I was expecting it to have the same size the image I provided but it is not. It is more like third of the image  ( and therefor only third of the image is displayed).

If I set the width to say 200dp then the full image is displayed. But I dont want to specify absolute values,I want to display according to the size of the drawable image

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post thw whole XML containing the view?

Comment: As tushar said, It would be difficult to answer without looking at the full xml layout.

Comment: The whole xml is HUGE. but why would it matter? If you are wondering about the "toLeftTo", then I replaced it with center horizontal and vertical and I got the same effect. I am not using weight sums on anything

Comment: I just tried the above view in an empty XML  ( basically only parent of linearlayout) and nothing else beside the progress bar. Same effect

Comment: Then it's not getting the proper images. In which folder have you kept them?

Comment: The images are in the drawable-mdpi and the xml is in the drawable folder.. When  I set the width  of the progress bar to the exact size of the image, it is showing the full image

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and I just found inner thickness ratio! I was trying to make a gauge so I had a png image and a progress bar behind it and they grew and shrank at different rates making it difficult to figure out how to get this to look good. Adjust the thickness ratio in your independent progress bar drawable and it should work!